# Problem with resizing a control

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to control it will have a dynamic size, I tested first when you increase the size of the control, worked perfectly, however when I Decreased the size of the event is not even called.
I am using the following event to call the function

```
ChatList.SizeChanged += ChatList_SizeChanged;

private void ChatList_SizeChanged (object sender, System.Windows.SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
  UpdateLayout ();
  CalculateSpace (e.NewSize.Width);
}
```

CalculateSpace function has the following code

```
private void CalculateSpace (double width)
{
  var size = width / _List.Count;
  foreach (var in personSelector _List)
    personSelector.Value.Width = size;
  }
}
```

Is there any reason for the event will not be called when the screen size diminishes?

Thanks

Comment: BTGMarco, because of the way this site works, it is expected that you take the time to accept an answer if it answered your question. You have asked 8 questions without accepting any answers. Please take the time to accept answers or you can expect little to no answers on this and future questions. Sorry, but it's just the way this community operates.

Answer (score 0):

Its very difficult to analyse what is going in the absence of good info the layout of your control and where its placed.  However I would expect to find that the control will always want to be no less in size as its content.  Hence as soon as you inflate the widths of its content you in effect set its minimum width.  When the available space gets small the control is not be sized down since it "needs" more.

Have you consided using a `Grid` with column definitions of 1* width.  When you add a new "person" element the control just add another column definition to the grid and add the approprieate Grid.Column property value to the new element.

The Grid will handle all this sizing stuff for you.